# VBA Pictures don't show in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, ms-office, excel-2010

I am confronted with a strange problem which occurs under Excel 2007.

I have created a document with 1000 rows (different products/ article numbers) and fetch the product pictures from the net with my little VBA Code

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ActiveCell.Text).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 100
```

Pictures do show in **Excel 2010**, even on other PCs
However they do not appear in **Excel 2007**, even in other formats like 97-03

Comment: This is a problem in 2007 SP1 only. Read: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/07/30/activesheet-pictures-insert-help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try alternative method of adding pictures to excel sheet. It will go as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
        Filename:=Activecell.Text, _
        linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=1600, Height:=1600
```

Few times I've found out it's more stable and reliable method of adding pictures.

**Edit** As pointed by @Julien Marrec below, using the code I provided you need to know proportion of the shape or you need to adjust it as a next step. I usually do it with this code:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Count)
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .Width = 200
End With
```

**Important!** if you add big picture you need to oversize it when adding (1600 px in the first portion of code). If not you will not be able to get the result of `.ScaleHeight method` in the second portion of code.

Comment: The problem with that is that you need to specify all dimensions when you might not know them

Comment: You need to specify a temporary value for and the width and height and then call ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight to reset it to original size. See alternate answer

Comment: @JulienMarrec, yes, exactly. But you provided the suggested workaround... I'll add it to my answer in a minute, too.

Comment: This was the perfect solution to my problem! Thank you a thousand times.

Comment: In Addition, i replaced Left:=40, Top:=40 with Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Top:=ActiveCell.Top as manual placement for 1000 rows wouldn't be that easy. Just to get the documentation right ;)